# Is it possible to wrap log.Logger functions without losing the line number prefix?

Tags: logging, go, callstack

When using the `log.Lshortfile` flag, the logger prefixes all log lines with the file name and line number of the logger function call, for example:

```
myfile.go:14: Hello, world!
```

If I wrap the log function like this, for instance:

```
func info(pattern string, args ...interface{}) {
    myLogger.Printf(pattern + "\n", args...)
}
```

Every line emitted by this function is going to be prefixed with the line number of the `Printf` call. That is as expected, but the desired behavior is for each line to be prefixed with the line number of the line where `info` is called.

Is there any way around it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Methods of [`log.Logger`](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#Logger) call the [`Logger.Output()`](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#Logger.Output) method to send the message to the appropriate output. `Logger.Output()` allows you to pass the `calldepth` (the number of frames to skip).

Unfortunately methods of `log.Logger` contain the `calldepth` "wired in", so you can't provide an offset to skip the wrapper function's frame.

But a much better alternative is to call this `Logger.Output()` from your wrapper, so you don't have to bother with frames and lines yourself. Also note that you don't need to append a newline `"\n"`, as the `log.Logger` type already does that if the message to be logged does not end with a newline.

So a better and shorter alternative:

```
var myLogger = log.New(os.Stdout, "[my]", log.Lshortfile)

func info(pattern string, args ...interface{}) {
    myLogger.Output(2, fmt.Sprintf(pattern, args...))
}
```

Testing it:

```
func main() {
    log.SetFlags(log.Lshortfile)
    log.Println("hello")
    info("world")
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/WKgcgzEbtV)):

```
main.go:11: hello
[my]main.go:12: world
```

As you can see, `info()` prints the proper line number (+1 compared to the line number printed by `log.Println()` in the previous line).

Comment: That's what I'm talking about :D Great answer

Answer (score 0):

I was going to include this in the question as my current workaround, but I suppose it is a valid answer. I'm hoping somebody can tell me of a logger config option I've missed that lets me adjust the depth the logger uses when it calls `runtime.Caller`.

A workaround is to remove the `log.Lshortfile` flag and implement the behavior manually:

```
func info(format string, args ...interface{}) {
    _, file, line, _ := runtime.Caller(1)

    prefix := fmt.Sprintf("%v:%v: ", path.Base(file), line)

    if logger != nil {
        logger.Printf(prefix+format+"\n", args...)
    }
}
```